# WCF Service Error HTTP

Tags: wcf

Using a WCF service to communicate with a website in a shared hosting environment.

Getting the following error:

Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException The requested service, 'http://www.mywebsite.com/myservice.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.

We have managed to 'reset' the service copying files to the project however, the service needs to run in an automated fashion during the evening hours and having very limited access to IIS has proven difficult. Is there a solution that might be found on the code and visual studio side of things. Cheers.

Comment: Q1: Have you just now deployed the website, or has the website worked before and suddenly started throwing this exception? and Q2: How did you deploy it, straight from within Visual Studio? finally, Q3: Which version of WCF are you using?

Comment: server's diagnostic trace log would be usefull.

Comment: The site has been deployed for some time using an .asmx solution. We switched to WCF about 3 months ago and it seemed to run without error during that time. The application was deployed using the website copy tool in VS 2010 with .NET 4.0 and WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your shared hosting environment, you may need to set some parameters in web.config to make it work; I had similar problems when deploying some services to my GoDaddy account, and the article at http://www.edoverip.com/edoverip/index.php/2009/01/30/running-wcf-on-godaddy/ had the steps I needed to do to get it running.